# View.INVISIBLE isn't work for me but View.GONE work good

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I'm working for app that has a Webview that load my website, and has a progress bar that loading when the page in my webview is loading. For start check how to do it I tried to create two buttons: one is stop progress bar and the second is start it.

My progress bar is load by default when the app is start. 
Now I created the button that stop this and button that start but the button that need to start this again isn't working after I stop this by the button that need to stop this. 
I thought that because that has Webview on all the page the loading start work again below the Webview and because it I defined that bottom margin of Webview will be to the progress bar and I saw that  when that the progress bar is work (when I open the app in start) the WebView to the progress bar (middle of the screen) and when I stop this by stop button it's up to end the screen. When I start this again by the start button it's not show the progress bar but it's up to middle of the screen.
I searched in google but I'm not find anything.
sorry for my bad English I'm only forteen years old...

Here my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="me.filtering.netsparkmobile.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<TextView
    android:text="!אבה ךורב"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/textView6" />




<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2" />


<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="stop progressbar"
    android:onClick="stopPB" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_send2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="start progressbar"
    android:onClick="startPB"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here part of  my JAVA code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ProgressBar PB1;
int ProgressBarStatus=1;


public void stopPB(View arg0) {
    ProgressBar PB1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

    PB1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
public void startPB(View arg0) {

    ProgressBar PB1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    PB1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


}
```

Comment: What error does it give when you use View.INVISIBLE ? Also, have you tried this approach; progressBar.setVisibility(0);    --visible
progressBar.setVisibility(4);    --invisible
progressBar.setVisibility(8);    --gone (like dismiss)

Comment: @HonorLT It's not give me error. It's not working but not give error. What did you mean progressBar.setVisibility(0);?? it's not possible command.

Answer (score 0):

Collllll!!!
I found my error!!!
I defined like this:

```
 PB1.setVisibility(View.**INVISIBLE**);
```

But need define like this:

```
PB1.setVisibility(View.**VISIBLE**);
```